# transform from type char to int produce different result

Tags: c++, string, char, int

I wonder in the code below that why the result of i and j is different.To my intuition,b also pointed to the address of a char with value 4.why do the result of i and j is different

```
char c='4';
const char *b;
int i,j;

i=atoi(string(1,c).c_str());
b=string(1,c).c_str();
j=atoi(b);
cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b = string(1,c).c_str();`

This creates a temporary `string` that goes out of scope after the expression. The problem is that the pointer returned by `c_str()` is only valid as long as the string it was called on lives and no non-const functions has been called on it.

If you go down this route of doing things, you need to make sure the original `string` is valid when you call `atoi`.

```
std::string s(1,c);
b = s.c_str();
j = atoi(b);
s.clear(); // b is no longer valid now!
```

Alternatively:

```
j = atoi(string(1,c).c_str());
```

Comment: As long as the string it was called on lives _and_ no non-const function has been called on it.

Comment: Does it mean in statement `b=string(1,c).c_str()`, the string is only a temporary object so the pinter `c_str` is not valid.

Comment: Yes, it's valid until the full expression it was created in finishes.

Answer (score 5):

```
b=string(1,c).c_str();
```

`b` points to a temporary object which is destroyed after this statement. It actually has **undefined behavior**.

A short way to convert char to int is:

```
int i = c- '0';
```

Answer (score 2):

on some architectures (os, compiler, stl implementation) the code produces "4 4" as expected. Try it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=41f2401a3fd0f9e80039f2e81baeee87-4c14052776b81b965e3761ffd8f9b825).

The problem is that the code relies on undefined behaviour, since it uses a pointer returned by an object which has been destroyed.

When you write

```
b = string(1,c).c_str();
```

you are creating a temporary object and asking it for a pointer to an array of characters. You assign this pointer to b and then the temporary object (which owns the memory b now points to) is destroyed. Assuming the library is "sane", such memory is going to be freed during the string destruction. Hence accessing the memory via the pointer b is undefined behaviour.

Of course you should not rely on undefined behaviour, even if it "works" on some occasions.